# Ordenar lista por longitud de Texto en ella

Tags: c#, android, json, lista, xamarin

Estoy almacenando el siguiente parámetro de un `Json`: `also_known_as` en una lista, pero necesito luego recuperar el texto mas largo de la lista.

Se me ocurrió almacenar la longitud de cada texto en otra lista y luego hacer un `.Sort()` para saber cual es el mas largo pero entonces pierdo el `índex`. De momento no se me ocurre como hacer esto de manera simple. Ideas?

```
{        "name": "Juan Perez",
        "also_known_as": [
                "Juancito",
                "El moncho",
                "El gran mocho"
        ],
        "gender": "male"
}
```

Comment: Podrias crear un objeto donde este incorporado el alias y un ID unico que seria index que quieres. Luego le das el sort y ya tendrias una lista ordenada. Luego si quieres saber el index te vas al objeto y tienes el ID unico que seria el index :D

Comment: La idea no esta mal pero ni idea como llevarla acabo igual que con la idea que se me ocurrió y que comente en el post jaja.

Comment: Puedes compartir el código donde creas la lista que quieres ordenar por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un método transform y pasas ese objeto donde lee also_knwon_as lo convierta a otro array

```
Arrays.sort(W, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
```